# Horizontal Navigation/Menu bar using angular Ngx-admin

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, ngx-admin

I am using angular Ngx-admin template for one my admin project. And planning to convert existing vertical navigation menu to horizontal navigation. Is there any feasibility/option with Ngx-admin? **if not, kindly suggest any free angular admin templates available for horizontal navigation?**

I have checked few of the templates but all are premium only.